# codeigniter:How to include a file with all css/js directories

Tags: php, codeigniter

Maybe it is easy, but I really stuck inside. And I am new in codeigniter only few days.
Here is my file directories:

```
webroot
   |--- assets
           |-- css
           |-- js
```

I want to put all css and js inside a file, then I just need to include this file inside my header.
I read quite alot post in stackoverflow and other tutorial, but I am still unable to success.
Inside application\config\constants.php

```
define('ASSET_PATH','assets/');
```

Inside application\config\config.php

```
$config['header_css']=array('style.css','bootstrap.css');
```

Then how can I load header_css in my page?I have this code in my views\login.php

```
<?php
    put_headers;
?>
```

I have a application\helpers\header_helper.php

```
    if(!function_exists('add_css')){
    function add_css($file='')
    {
        $str = '';
        $ci = &get_instance();
        $header_css = $ci->config->item('header_css');

        if(empty($file)){
            return;
        }

        if(is_array($file)){
            if(!is_array($file) && count($file) <= 0){
                return;
            }
            foreach($file AS $item){   
                $header_css[] = $item;
            }
            $ci->config->set_item('header_css',$header_css);
        }else{
            $str = $file;
            $header_css[] = $str;
            $ci->config->set_item('header_css',$header_css);
        }
    }
}
if(!function_exists('put_headers')){
    function put_headers()
    {
        $str = '';
        $ci = &get_instance();
        $header_css = $ci->config->item('header_css');
        // $header_js  = $ci->config->item('header_js');

        foreach($header_css AS $item){
            $str .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.base_url().ASSET_PATH.'/css/'.$item.'" type="text/css" />'."\n";
        }
        return $str;
    }
}
```

Comment: something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url()/assests/js/file.js?>" />`

Comment: hmm..that's mean define constants is nothing?

Comment: `define('ASSET_PATH', FCPATH . 'assets/');`